# typescript push on array does not add element to it

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried adding an element to an array in angular2(typescript). It neither throws any error nor adds the element to the array.

code snippet:

```
 let _dataSets:number[] = new Array(this.paymentModes.length);

for (let i = 0; i < this.paymentModes.length; i++) {
    let paymentMode = this.paymentModes[i];
    _dataSets.push(paymentMode.paymentModeTotalSales);
  }
  console.log(_dataSets);
```

is there anything wrong?

*paymentModes is an array from WS response.

Comment: Maybe `this.paymentModes` is empty and so no item is added?

Answer (score 0):

Use array map, ensure attribute paymentMode.paymentModeTotalSales is of type number, if not, convert it; set default value to 0:

```
let dataSets:number[];
dataSets = this.paymentModes.map(paymentMode => Number(paymentMode.paymentModeTotalSales || 0));
console.log(dataSets);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see is if paymentModeTotalSales is not a number.
For e.g., following works fine. You can see value 10 in alert. You can try running this [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=module%20Test%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20class%20PaymentMode%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20paymentModeTotalSales%3A%20number%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%20(paymentModeTotalSales%3A%20number)%20%7B%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.paymentModeTotalSales%20%3D%20paymentModeTotalSales%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_dataSets%3A%20PaymentMode%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_paymentModes%3A%20PaymentMode%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_paymentModes.push(new%20PaymentMode(10))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_paymentModes.push(new%20PaymentMode(12))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20_paymentModes.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20paymentMode%20%3D%20_paymentModes%5Bi%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_dataSets.push(new%20PaymentMode(paymentMode.paymentModeTotalSales))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(_dataSets%5B0%5D.paymentModeTotalSales)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

```
module Test { 

   class PaymentMode {
        public paymentModeTotalSales: number;           
        constructor (paymentModeTotalSales: number) {   
            this.paymentModeTotalSales = paymentModeTotalSales;
            }
    }    
    let _dataSets: PaymentMode[] = [];
    let _paymentModes: PaymentMode[] = [];
    _paymentModes.push(new PaymentMode(10));
    _paymentModes.push(new PaymentMode(12));
    for (let i = 0; i < _paymentModes.length; i++) {
    let paymentMode = _paymentModes[i];
    _dataSets.push(new PaymentMode(paymentMode.paymentModeTotalSales));
    }
    alert(_dataSets[0].paymentModeTotalSales);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Shailendra for your reply. paymentModeTotalSales  is a number defined in another class. I was doing the same thing but It did not work for me. I will also try this and update you.